# How to retrieve date in a range Mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-mongo

MongoDB sample data:

```
   {
      "couseId": "String",
      "assignmentId": "String",
      "studentId": "String",
      "submissionId": "String",
      "version": "String",
      "grade": "int"
    }
```

I want to retrieve aggregate data in a range (all grades in between 50-100). Actually i want to get the count of the above grade range.

How to i do this using java spring mongo. It would be great if some one can post a code example.

**Update:**

Is it possible to get how many students are there in a particular range using Spring Aggregation Framework ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `@Query` annotation in your repository. Here is an example.

**Course.java**

```
@Document(collection = "courses")
public class Course {
    @Id
    private String courseId;
    private String assignmentId;
    private String studentId;
    private String submissionId;
    private String version;

    @Indexed
    private int grade;

    //constructor and getters and setters
}
```

**CourseRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface CourseRepository extends MongoRepository<Couse, String> {

    // just put an JSON, just like MongoDB query
    @Query("{grade: {$gte: 50, $lte: 100}}")
    List<Course> findInGradeRange();
}
```

I hope it helps.

**EDIT**

But, If you want to set the range dynamically (for example 20-50), you can do it like this.

**CourseRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface CourseRepository extends MongoRepository<Course, String> {}
```

**CourseService.java**

```
@Service
public class CourseService {

    @Autowired
    private CourseRepository couseRepository;

    public List<Course> findByRange(int min, int max) {
        return courseRepository.findAll().stream()
                .filter(c -> c.getGrade() >= min && c.getGrade() <= max)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get how many students are there in a particular range using Spring Aggregation Framework ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it, just return the size of this list, and change the method return type to `int`